# Program that can terminate other programs after a certain period of time

Tags: windows, automation

Is there an application for windows that can terminate other programs after a certain period of time.
I would use this program for shutting down movie player when I want to watch only 30 minutes of lecture that lasts an hour for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automating what you are asking and many other things in Windows there is a great and free scripting tool and app called AutoIt v3 which can do what you want with a little bit of basic programming (or a few clicks that can generate that script). You will find a lot of information on their [site](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

For example to do what you are asking could be as easy as writing (or generating) something close to

```
$Timer1= TimerInit()

While True
     If TimerDiff($Timer1) > 30*60*1000 Then
        ProcessClose(<YOUR APP>)
     EndIf
     Sleep(1000)
WEnd
```

Autoit is very powerful and you can of course add more logic and function depending on your needs.

Comment: Tnx. Can you tell me what can I put in <YOUR APP> other than PID? Because PID changes, I've tried, app name, and full path of app. @user3134164

Comment: You should be able to put the app name such as "notepad.exe" for example. See: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ProcessClose.htm If your app name does not work maybe you are using it a bit differently check with Task Manager to use the correct name (Ctlr+Alt+Del Start Task Manager)

Answer (score -1):

Another well known program that can take care of many different kinds of automation is [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/#keyfeatures).

With AutoHotkey you can write a script that is manually executed or is started with Windows and is running while Windows is running. It should meet your requirements because it can...

- check if a program is running or a window is open
- wait for a given duration before doing something specific
- close a window/program

You can also build user interfaces (for example dialog boxes) to interact with so that you can have better control over your scripts.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations – and thanks for sharing! Unfortunately, this post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Especially missing: How does it meet the requirements? How can it accomplish what the OP asked for? See e.g. how the other answer explains this.